# Inequalities with absolute value

Tags: inequality

Please may I have some help with this inequality:

> $ |x-1|(x^2-4)\geq 0 $

Thank you

Comment: I do not want to solve my homework problem. Kindly solve it for me. Thank you.

Comment: Try sketching a graph

Comment: If $x\neq 1$, you get $x^2-4\geq 0$. Otherwise $x=1$ is also OK.

Answer (score 0):

$$
|x-1|(x^{2}-4)=
|x-1|(x-2)(x+2).
$$

Now, this function changes signs at $x=-2$ and $x=2$. Plug in a value of $x$ in each of the intervals $(-\infty, -2)$, $(-2,2)$, and $(2,+\infty)$ to see when the function is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Since we always have $|x-1|\geq 0 $ we must solve $x^2\geq 4$ and thus $|x|\geq 2$. So $x\in(-\infty, -2]\cup [2,\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

we have to solve $$|x-1|(x^2-4)\geq 0$$ at first $$|x-1|\geq 0$$ for all real $x$:
now we solve $$(x^2-4)\geq 0$$ this is equivalent to $$(x-2)(x+2)\geq 0$$ and from here we get
$$x\geq 2$$ or $$x\le -2$$